# C++ attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++

I am trying to temporary store a vector of unique pointers and switch them between 2 objects. Here I try to move the ownership of the vector to a temporary vector named `oldcards`.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>> oldCards = std::move(player.getBuildingCards());
player.setBuildingCards(std::move(otherPlayer.getBuildingCards()));
otherPlayer.setBuildingCards(std::move(oldCards));
```

Player.cpp

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>> const& Player::getBuildingCards() const
{
    return this->buildingCards;
}

void Player::setBuildingCards(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>> buildingCards)
{
    this->buildingCards = std::move(buildingCards);
}
```

Player.h

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>> buildingCards;`

To conclude: I want to swap 2 vectors, I want `player` to have the ownership of the vector of `otherPlayer` and vice versa. However, I get the: attempting to reference a deleted function error. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "and switch them between" - sounds like `std::swap`.

Comment: Why all the unnecessary explicit `this->`?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to temporary store a vector of unique pointers and switch them between 2 objects.

Why? Using [`std::vector::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) would accomplish the same thing with less effort. (Note that this swap most likely should occur within a member function, so there would be no need to use the public accessor functions.)

> `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>>`**`const`**`& Player::getBuildingCards() const`

This returns a `const` reference. You are not allowed to change something marked `const`. Moving data out of something counts as changing that something, so moving from `getBuildingCards()` is not allowed.

> `void Player::setBuildingCards(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>> buildingCards)`

This function takes a **copy** of a vector as a parameter. Since a vector of `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, this function signature is DOA. (For the intended purpose, you would want the type of the parameter to be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>>`**`&&`** to indicate that you will be moving from the parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move from `cons T&` so copy constructor of `oldCards` is called which is of course deleted. `player.getBuildingCards()` cannot change the `player` instance anyway because you marked it as const.

Cleanest solution (at least according to me) would to implement `swapBuildingCards` friend function:

```
class Player
{
    //...
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Building>> buildingCards;

    friend static void swapBuildingCards(Player& p1, Player &p2)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(p1.buildingCards,p2.buildingCards);
    }
};
```